# ClickOnce Deployment of an Application with more then one executable file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I am trying to deploy an application with two executable files one of which is the application it self.

I used the publish tub on the VS 2008 and tried to publish manually using the MageUI.exe.

in both cases I get this error (in regards to the second executable file):

> "Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the
>   downloaded assembly"

Dose Any one know how to publish an application with two executable files?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem by publishing the second executable project.

Hope this helps someone else
Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 0):

I recall dealing with an application a few months ago that handled this exact issue by adding references to the other executable projects within the main "program" executable.  It seemed to work for that project, and I've been supporting it as of late without much, if any, issue.